# Why is Xamarin inserting '+' signs instead of spaces when sending Emails using the Xamarin.Essentials.EmailMessage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using the code snippet below from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios) and am getting '+' signs instead of spaces in my Outlook email app.  All other text is correct.  I do not think I am doing anything fancy with the strings, but I am using string interpolation.

```
public async Task SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> recipients)
{
    try
    {
        var message = new EmailMessage
        {
            Subject = @"{StoreName} Needs a Payer",
            Body = @"It needs a separate payer...",
            To = recipients,
            //Cc = ccRecipients,
            //Bcc = bccRecipients
        };
        await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fbsEx)
    {
        // Email is not supported on this device
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some other exception occurred
    }
}
```

This is a .NET Xamarin iOS app.  What can I do to make sure spaces are used and not '+' signs?

I tried changing the BodyFormat property and got the following results:  Setting the BodyFormat to Text does not change the behavior. Still get + signs instead of spaces, *but* if I use a iOS Mail application, the spaces are fine. If I set it to BodyFormat HTML, the Outlook application just crashes, but the iOS Mail application is fine.

Comment: try setting the `BodyFormat` property

Comment: @Jason So weird behavior.  Setting the BodyFormat to Text does not change the behavior.  Still get + signs instead of spaces, BUT if I use a iOS Mail application, the spaces are fine.  If I set it to BodyFormat HTML, the Outlook application just crashes, but the iOS Mail application is fine.  Very frustrating.

Comment: have you tried urlencoding it?  If that doesn't work I'd probably file a bug in the Essentials repo

Comment: Can you show what the text looks like? How do you interpolate your string? Would be nice to include that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update to the latest version of *Xamarin.Essentials*.

Comment: What version was it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Outlook issue in the iOS app only.

To fix it, use `%20` instead of space, and it will work fine with all mail clients.

Comment: That just displays it with %20 instead of + signs.  This is using BodyFormat text, Outlook just crashes with BodyFormat html.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **Uri.EscapeDataString** method to encode the string and then we can pass it in the body and subject.

Comment: That just replaces the '+' signs with '%20'

Comment: '%20's when using BodyFormat of text.  Outlook crashes with any BodyFormat html.